# Python REPL: issuing commands in advance to execute after block

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

This is a bit of an odd question; it came up in the context of a tool that exposes a Python API, which we spend a lot of time querying interactively from the REPL.  The particular idiom causing issues is something like this:

```
for var in slow_generator_of_giant_list():
    stats = update(stats, var)
print stats
```

To enter this at the REPL, I can type this:

```
>>> for var in slow_generator_of_giant_list():
...    stats = update(stats, var)
...
```

If I now attempt to type the `print`, I get a syntax error due to improper indentation.  (Or else I put the print inside the loop and do it on every iteration.)

But if I hit enter to go to the next line, the loop runs immediately, and I have to wait for it to finish, or type the print command in the face of possible output coming at me, etc.

Obviously I can define a function containing the above, and it might be worth saving into a file anyway, but in the general case we're constructing these on the fly, and it would be nice to have a way to "schedule" a command to run after the end of a loop from the REPL.  In a language with block delimiters, I could of course put it after the ending delimiter (and any necessary statement separator).  But my coworkers and I were stumped trying to do something similar here.

Is there perhaps an ugly abuse of Pythonic syntax that will do the trick that my coworkers and I couldn't think of?  Or a recommended way to avoid the problem while still making it easy to throw together ad hoc interactive queries?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not beautiful, but this should work:

```
>>> mygen = slow_generator_of_giant_list()
>>> try:
...     while True: stats = update(stats, mygen.next())
... except StopIteration:
...     print stats
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopheD.  That will work if the slow list-generating function is actually a Generator.  In some cases it is unfortunately just a very slow function that returns the entire list all at once at the end, in which case I'm back to the same issue: no way to request the try block until after waiting for the generator to return.

Answer (score 0):

I would just say that you would find it easier just to not use the interactive shell for this.

It's not much effort to save a file and run it. You only have to keep it around for as long as you use it.

I actually have found this answering on SO. I keep a file open in my text editor with a terminal in the right directory, and just use it as a scratchpad for mocking up answers in.